# PerformancePoint 2013 connection issue with Designer

Tags: 2013, performancepoint

I have set up Performancepoint services in a 2013 environment with SQL 2014.  It appears the service is running fine.  Set it to use unattended service account.  The issue is when I open designer from the bi center performance point content library all options are grayed out and all I see in the left pane is untitled workspace.  The unattended service acct is also do.writer on content database. Missing something with permissions I believe.